# Running a function with different size of vectors iteratively in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I created a function ("analiz") as below:

```
std_dev <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))

analiz <- function(x){
  sprintf("Mean: %.2f, StandardDev: %.2f", mean(x), std_dev(x))}
```

And I would like to run the function ("analiz") for the variables below respectively:

```
vec1 <- sample(1:1000,10)
vec2 <- sample(1:1000,20)
vec3 <- sample(1:1000,50)
.
.
.
vec10 <- sample(1:1000,300)
```

How can I do that without writing "analiz(vecN)" 10 times?

Comment: Well, don't create 10 different `vec` variables in the first place. Create a list like `vec <- lapply(c(10,20,50, ..., 300), function(x) sample(1:1000, x)` Then you can do `lapply(vec, analiz)`

Comment: @MrFlick many thanks. However, actually I created them all as an example. In my work, vectors are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get all the objects into a `list` with `mget`, loop over the `list` with `lapply` and apply the 'analiz' function

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "^vec\\d+$"))
lapply(lst1, analiz)
```

Comment: many thanks, it worked. Could you please explain the "^vec\\d+$" section? Is it regex? I'd like to learn it.

Comment: @uguros it is a regex pattern that checks for object names that starts with (`^`) the substring "vec" followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) at the end (`$`) of the string

Comment: @uguros if your object names are different and there are no patterns, then you may have to get those in a list manually i.e. `list(vec1, vec2, vec3, ...., vecN)`